# Using result of Solve in further calculations

Tags: equation-solving, products

I'm trying to make a code for Gauss-Legendre quadrature. First I find the roots of the polyinomial with

```
roots[n_,x_]:=Solve[LegendreP[n, x] == 0]
```

Then I need to make $n$ functions which are products of $n-1$ terms, in the form of

$$
\prod_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq i}}^{n} \frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}
$$

with the $x_j$ being elements of `roots[n,x]`, but I have to exclude $x_i$ in each function.

I tried this:

```
w[i_, x_] := Product[(x - roots[n, x][[j]])/(roots[n, x][[i]] - 
   roots[n, x][[j]]), {j, 1, n}, j!=i]
```

but I get an error *Part specification j is neither an integer nor a list of integers*. So now I have two concerns, is there a way to make a product (mind you, I need to make $n$ products for an arbitrary integer $n$) with skipping one iteration, and how do I use the results I get from Solve in the definition of w?

Comment: Use `If[]`.$\phantom{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract roots from a `Solve` command using the replacement operation `/.`:

```
xroots[n_]:= Solve[LegendreP[n, x] == 0]
roots[n_]:= x /. xroots[n]
```

Your `Product` call combined with an `If` condition, as suggested in the comment above, should do the trick.

```
w[i_, x_] := 
Product[    
If[i==j,1,
(x - roots[n][[j]])/(roots[n][[i]] - roots[n][[j]])
]
,{j,1,n}]
```