# Another using Solve output for further calculations

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction

I probably missed a question already posted as this topic seems common, but I looked at several, e.g. [Using result of Solve in further calculations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86970/using-result-of-solve-in-further-calculations)
and am a little stuck. I didn't understand the use of `Prefix` in this one (which only had 1 solution anyway): [Using Solve outputs for further calculations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/169757/using-solve-outputs-for-further-calculations)

Even this one: [Using the result of Solve in subsequent calculations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6796/using-the-result-of-solve-in-subsequent-calculations?rq=1) which looked promising, doesn't seem to have a way of automatically selecting solutions (this one only had 1 again). Maybe I am overlooking how to use these methods but I cannot make the connection...

If I have something like,

```
eq1 = x^2 - 3*y^2 + 3
sol = Reduce[eq1 == 0, y, Complexes]
sol[[1]][[2]]
eq2[i_] = 100 + (y /. y -> sol[[i]][[2]])

Part::pkspec1: The expression i cannot be used as a part specification.
```

I made sure not to use SetDelayed, and I know I can do things like,

```
100 + (y /. y -> sol[[1]][[2]])
```

where `100 + y` is a new function, but the `1` is chosen by the script itself automatically and can't be 'hard-coded'.

What kind of methodology can one use when there are functions calling functions calling.... etc, that ultimately depend on an automatic choice of a solution set?

PS.

I also tried name a set of rules, but I cannot hold the left side unevaluated (like a ' in Lisp), [how do I control the output of Reduce function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121337/how-do-i-control-the-output-of-reduce-function)

```
solSet = Table[Unevaluated[y] -> y /. y -> sol[[i]][[2]], {i, 1, 2}]
```

I guess this is more likely to be (though still fails)

```
solSet = {ToRules[sol]}
eq3[i_] = 100 + y/.solSet[[i]]
```

---

What I would want is (in pseudo-code):

```
eq1 = x^2 -3*y^2 + 3
sol = Reduce[eq1==0,y,Complexes]
eq2[i_] = 100 + sol[[i]][[2]]
  eq2[1] = 100 + solution_one
  eq2[2] = 100 + solution_two
eq3[i_,j_] = A*eq2[i] + B*eq2[j];
etc
etc
```

Comment: What do you want to get as a result?

Comment: well i guess i want a function that uses an index to select which solution value to use, e.g. eq2[1] ----> 100 + sol[[1]][[2]] or eq2[2] -----> 100 + sol[[2]][[2]]...and in even more nested functions

Comment: But the solution `sol` is `y == -(Sqrt[3 + x^2]/Sqrt[3]) || y == Sqrt[3 + x^2]/Sqrt[3]`. You can use a replacement `eq2[i_] := sol[[i]] /. {y -> 100 + z}`

Comment: well I get then: `100 + z == -(Sqrt[3 + x^2]/Sqrt[3])` which isn't really a result (unless I'm doing something wrong). But also, if the enveloping function isn't simple (like 100 + last_choice_of_solution) then it would be difficult to type.

Comment: The question remains, what do you want to get?

Comment: hello, maybe you did not see my comment on 'pseudo code' I added because of your last question. Basically to use prior solutions by an index in a function. @J. M. is computer-less answered it perfectly, and I in an okay manner. I haven't selected answer yet is all. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much more in the spirit of the question, [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50) had a better answer:

```
In[1]:= sol = 
 y /. {ToRules[
    Reduce[x^2 - 3 y^2 + 3 == 0, y, Complexes, 
     Backsubstitution -> True]]}

Out[1]= {-(Sqrt[3 + x^2]/Sqrt[3]), Sqrt[3 + x^2]/Sqrt[3]}

In[2]:= eq2[i_] := 100 + Indexed[sol, i]

In[4]:= eq2[1]
eq2[2]

Out[4]= 100 - Sqrt[3 + x^2]/Sqrt[3]

Out[5]= 100 + Sqrt[3 + x^2]/Sqrt[3]
```

Noting that the original problem was complaints of using `[[i]]` (I think effectively `Part[]`) to reference the solutions, I add the interesting (to me) observation that the function `oop` uses `Part` but does not suffer from the same error, and allows the further building of functions.

```
In[6]:= oop[i_, ch_] := h /. Part[Solve[eq2[i] + h^2 == 0, h], ch, 1]

In[8]:= oop[1, 1]
oop[1, 2]
oop[2, 1]
oop[2, 2]

Out[8]= -Sqrt[-100 + Sqrt[3 + x^2]/Sqrt[3]]

Out[9]= Sqrt[-100 + Sqrt[3 + x^2]/Sqrt[3]]

Out[10]= -(Sqrt[-300 - Sqrt[3] Sqrt[3 + x^2]]/Sqrt[3])

Out[11]= Sqrt[-300 - Sqrt[3] Sqrt[3 + x^2]]/Sqrt[3]
```

---

My original answer,

```
In[1]:= eq1 = x^2 - 3*y^2 + 3

Out[1]= 3 + x^2 - 3 y^2

In[2]:= sol = Reduce[eq1 == 0, y, Complexes, Backsubstitution -> True]

Out[2]= y == -(Sqrt[3 + x^2]/Sqrt[3]) || y == Sqrt[3 + x^2]/Sqrt[3]

In[3]:= sol[[1]][[2]]

Out[3]= -(Sqrt[3 + x^2]/Sqrt[3])

In[4]:= eq2[i_] := 100 + sol[[i]][[2]]

In[5]:= eq2[1]

Out[5]= 100 - Sqrt[3 + x^2]/Sqrt[3]

In[6]:= eq2[2]

Out[6]= 100 + Sqrt[3 + x^2]/Sqrt[3]
```

Comment: You could also do `sol = y /. {ToRules[Reduce[x^2 - 3 y^2 + 3 == 0, y, Complexes, Backsubstitution -> True]]}` and then `eq2[i_] := 100 + Indexed[sol, i]`.

Comment: I like a lot better! If it was an answer I'd accept it.

Comment: I was not able to test that code because I'm only using a smartphone. If it worked, I'm fine with you editing your answer to include it, and I can then upvote your answer. :)